# Request.UrlReferrer is not working in IE8 and working fine IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, referrer

I have Close button on my ASP.NET MVC page.
I wrote the following code to go back to previous page. 
It is working fine in IE9 but throwing error in IE8.

```
 $('#Close').click(function () {
          window.location.href= '@Request.UrlReferrer';

        });
```

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error does it throw? Also browsers usually have Back button. What's the point of writing such button in your UI?

Comment: Sometimes clients just want that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referer is not required by the HTTP specification, so you can't really rely on it. You can use this though

```
$('#Close').click(function () {
  window.history.back();
});
```